# Overwriting CSS markup to cancel current markup

Tags: html, css

For the website I have to maintain I need to add a bit of CSS. Unfortunately, there are some legal issues between my company and the company that build the website. This means I have no access to the files on the server. However, I have a built-in option to add custom CSS that is loaded inline in the header.

The current CSS theme file has this line:

```
@media (min-width: 769px)
.account-page .address-item:nth-child(3n+1), .account-page .order-item:nth-child(3n+1), .account-page .request-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

This needs to be changed from (3n+1) to (2n+1).
So I tried to re-write the CSS and put it into the custom CSS field.

```
.account-page .address-item:nth-child(2n+1) {
margin-left: 0;
clear: both;
}
```

This works good, but doesn't cancel out the other CSS. The style given in the code above is effective on the 1st and 2rd item (which is good) but (thanks to the original code in the theme file) its also effective on the 4th item.

I tried to add:

```
.account-page .address-item:nth-child(3n+1) {

}
```

But it doesn't do anything. Both the items mentioned in the original piece of CSS (margin-left and clear) are not mentioned in the other items, so I wouldn't know what value to give them.

Does anybody know a method how I can completely cancel out the first CSS code without editing the original CSS theme file?

Comment: In terms of specificity the only way that you'd be able to overwrite this and for it to always 'win' would be for you to use inline styles (but don't do this). See; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity. It may also depend on the order in which your CSS file loads. If your CSS file loads after the theme file, then you should be able to overwrite the style.

Comment: You first have to overwrite the `3n+1` selectors to the styling like it used to be, then add `2n+1` afterwards. You just add an empty block with the `3n+1` selector. This will not overwrite the styling. You would need to include `clear: none;` and `margin-left: [the original margin value]px;`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. The answer below seems to work in my situation and even in cross-browser I get the desired result now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override your css, without changing current values, copy the selector and set values to default like this

```
.account-page .address-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
margin-left: auto;
clear: none;
}
```

this selector should be under the first one, if it still has no try this

```
.account-page .address-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
margin-left: auto!important;
clear: none!important;
}
```

Comment: this is wrong! he doesn't want the `2n+1` to be overwrited!

Comment: I used this code and changed (3n+1) into (2n+1) and it seems to have given priority to the 2n+1 styling. In console I can still see the original code, but it has been crossed out and seems to be ignored. Trying this out in several browsers gave the same result.
So it seems this method works for me. Thanks Marko.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that this helped you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you should do this:

```
.account-page .address-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
    margin-left: auto!important;
    clear: none!important;
}
```

add this to the end of the file

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is similar to the one above, and that one seems to work for me. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To make your values override the originals, you need to add !important to the end of the values like the bellow snippet.  The !important rule is a way to make your CSS cascade but also have the rules you feel are most crucial always be applied. A rule that has the !important property will always be applied no matter where that rule appears in the CSS document.

```
.account-page .address-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
    margin-left: auto !important;
    clear: none !important;
}
```